# How to pass variable from Namespace to Reference namespace

Tags: c#, qr-code, nuget-package

My brain is broken. The program is setup to ask the user for an address. A simple console question that puts the users input into a string. Then I wish to pass the variable to a reference class library to put the string into a QRcode "barcode".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using QRmaker;

namespace AddressInq
{
    class Program
    { 
        public class getInput
    {
        public static string input { get; set; }
    }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the address: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The QR code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using QRCoder;

namespace QRmaker
{
     class program
        {

        public void codeMake()
        { 
        QRCodeGenerator generator = new QRCodeGenerator();

        QRCodeData qrCodeData = generator.CreateQrCode(input, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);

        QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);

        Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
        qrCodeImage.Save("Address.bmp");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you pass input as an argument to codeMake? Like codeMake(string input)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In QRMaker:

```
namespace QRmaker
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void codeMake(string input)
        { 
            var generator = new QRCodeGenerator();
            var qrCodeData = generator.CreateQrCode(input, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
            var qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
            var qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
            qrCodeImage.Save("Address.bmp");
        }
    }
}
```

In AddressInq:

```
namespace AddressInq
{
    class Program
    { 
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Please enter the address: ");
           QRmaker.Program.codeMake(Console.ReadLine());
       }
    }
}
```

What I did was to convert the `codeMake` method to `static` so that you do not have to instantiate the `Program` class to access it ...
You have to call the `Program` `class` that is in the `QRmaker` namespace including the namespace before the name of the class: `Namespace.Class.Method`.